# SQL: Insert Into with multiple case whens - syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a syntax error on "then" and I'm not sure why. 
I'm trying to insert 4 data in an sp, where two of them are date functions and the last one is hardcoded based on what actually exists on the table.

```
insert into tblcustomer 
  (
    customerid,  
    customerjoinDate, 
    customerexpiryDate, 
    customergroupid
  )
select 
    @person_id, 
    GetDate(), 
    dateadd (year, 1, GetDate()), 
    case            
        when exists
            (

                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        customerid = @person_id and 
                        customergroupid = 35
             )
        then 1            
        when exists
            (
                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        customerid = @person_id and 
                        customergroupid = 33

            )
        then 2            
        when exists
            (

                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        customerid = @person_id and 
                        customergroupid = 37

            )
        then 3          
        when exists
            (

                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        customerid = @person_id and 
                        customergroupid = 36

            )
        then 4
        when exists
            (

                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        customerid = @person_id and 
                        customergroupid = 34

            )
        then 5               

    END 
from tblcustomer
where NOT EXISTS (select 2 from tblcustomer where customerid = @person_id and customergroupid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

I'm guessing I can't just put the last value after then, so should I declare a variable? (Couldn't do so before select).

EDIT - Did some touch up now and I get a DBengine error saying that I'm trying to insert a null value to the customergroupid field?? Doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Clearly this `..else        end         case..` part is wrong

Comment: Are all of these conditions supposed to be part of the same `CASE WHEN` chain?  The syntax is `CASE WHEN <expression> THEN value WHEN <expression> THEN value WHEN <expression> THEN value ELSE value END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correcting your syntax, you are missing a parenthesis after each `WHERE NOT EXISTS` pairing, and the `... else end case ...` structure pointed out in the comments is wrong.  If I were to fix those two errors, the SQL would look like this:

```
insert into tblcustomer 
  (
    customerid, 
    customerjoinDate, 
    customerexpiryDate, 
    customergroupid
  )
select 
    @membership_id, 
    GetDate(), 
    dateadd (year, 1, GetDate()), 
    case            
        when exists
            (
                select customergroupid 
                from tblcustomer 
                where not exists
                    (
                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        (customerid = @membership_id and 
                        customergroupid = 1)
                    )
            )
        then 33            
        when exists
            (
                select customergroupid 
                from tblcustomer 
                where not exists
                    (
                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        (customerid = @membership_id and 
                        customergroupid = 2)
                    )
            )
        then 34            
        when exists
            (
                select customergroupid 
                from tblcustomer 
                where not exists
                    (
                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        (customerid = @membership_id and 
                        customergroupid = 3)
                    )
            )
        then 35          
        when exists
            (
                select customergroupid 
                from tblcustomer 
                where not exists
                    (
                    select * 
                    from tblcustomer 
                    where 
                        (customerid = @membership_id and 
                        customergroupid = 4)
                    )
            )
        then 36         
    END 
from tblcustomer
```

Unfortunately, I don't think that correcting the syntax of your statement is enough, since your actual condition makes no real sense: what you are saying, essentially, is:

> If a record exists in my table where no record exists in my table for
>   this customer with a group ID of 1, then the CustomerGroupID should
>   equal 33

See the redundancy there? Can you add a comment describing exactly what condition you are trying to implement for the CustomerGroupID?

Comment: Ah perhaps I should have used IF and ELSE cases instead. 
What I'm trying to do is to insert value into that table based on what the current customergroupid already exists (from 33-36) and making sure that group ids are not currently present for 1-4 by inserting them individually. 
So if I have a group id that has 34 value then I'd like to insert into that table their membership id, current date and incremented date (for another year) as well as the groupid 2 because it's current group id is 34.